# Access Properties from Knockout Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

**Here is the scenario:**

I currently have an object that looks like the following:

[image]

After running `modal.PersonInfo` I get the object returned starting at **line 3.** *See image above.*

> **Question:** Within my HTML, how can I call `FirstName`and `LastName`

**Error States:**

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return PersonInfo().FirstName}" Message PersonInfo is not defined`

**JavaScript:**

```
function Person() {
    var modal = this;
    modal.PersonInfo = ko.observable('');

    modal.setData = function (id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/Person/UserInformation?id=' + id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                modal.setPersonInfo(data);

                $('#person-modal').modal('show');
            }
        });

        modal.setPersonInfo = function (data) {
            modal.PersonInfo = data;
        }
    }
};
```

**HTML**
My thought was that I could do the following:

```
<p data-bind="text: PersonInfo().FirstName"></p>
<p data-bind="text: PersonInfo().LastName"></p>
```

Comment: What are you calling `applyBindings` on?  Also, `setPersonInfo` is going to replace your `observable` with a plain javascript object.  You need to use something like `ko.mapping.fromJS()` to keep it observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line *replaces* the observable, instead of assigning the value:

```
modal.PersonInfo = data;
```

Try this instead:

```
modal.PersonInfo(data)
```

There's also a misplaced closing brace: `model.setPersonInfo` was *inside* `model.setData`

See [working demo](https://jsbin.com/doriqarexi/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: thanks for the help. However, my HTML still fails... It says that PersonInfo doesn't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, while debugging and typing `data` I get this: `Object { FirstName: "Frankie", LastName: "Jones", Age: 55 }`

Comment: Thanks for the help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to just use some kind of mapping, for instance ko.mapping. Make sure you bind your view model, start your function in some way and you should be ok.

```js
var DemoPage = (function () {
    function DemoPage() {
     var _this = this;
        _this.PersonInfo = ko.observable({});
        _this.setData = function (id) {
            // some ajax that returns data
            var _data = { 
             FirstName: 'Frankie',
                LastName: 'Jones'
            };
            _this.setPersonInfo(_data);
            //$('#person-modal').modal('show');
     };
       _this.setPersonInfo = function (data) {
          ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, _this.PersonInfo());
       };
      
     this.setData();
    }
    return DemoPage;
})();

var demoApp = new DemoPage();

ko.applyBindings(demoApp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>

<p data-bind="text: PersonInfo().FirstName"></p>
<p data-bind="text: PersonInfo().LastName"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this takes on a whole different way of writing the code. Is there any easy way to alter the code I've written to solve my issue?

Comment: not sure what do you mean different, it's pretty much your code with slightly different naming conventions. The only change that you didn't include in your code is the initialization of KO bindings, and instead of replacing the data value, you can either do mapping `ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, _this.PersonInfo());` or just `this.PersonInfo(data)`. You can see the advantages of using mapping here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html